# Build PHP extension and use call_user_function

Tags: php, c, php-internals

I write a code for build an extension to connect to mysql database via `mysql_connect`.

My code is compiled, but when I want to use my function in PHP, it take a loop and not work probably.
here is my C++ code:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(ig_connect_to_database)
{
zval fname, *args[3], *retval = NULL;

ZVAL_STRING(&fname, "mysql_connect", 0);

MAKE_STD_ZVAL(args[0]);
ZVAL_STRING(args[0], "localhost", 1);

MAKE_STD_ZVAL(args[1]);
ZVAL_STRING(args[1], "root", 1);

MAKE_STD_ZVAL(args[2]);
ZVAL_STRING(args[2], "", 1);

if (call_user_function(EG(function_table), NULL, &fname, retval, 3, args TSRMLS_CC) == SUCCESS) {

    zval_ptr_dtor(&retval);
    zval_ptr_dtor(&args[1]);
    zval_ptr_dtor(&args[0]);
}

}
```

---

any body can help me?

I just want to return my resource connection.

I know that "retval" is myresource but I do not know how can return this resource into my php code.

Comment: I don't think retval can be NULL. It can be if you use call_user_function_ex() instead, as that function takes a zval ** for the return value.

Comment: I just solve the problem with define retval: zval retval. I have one problem to return my resource connection. c++ compiler tell me 'zif_ig_connect_to_database' : 'void' function returning a value. how can I return my resource?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know it is true if I answer my question or not but my problem is solved with this code:

```c
*return_value = retval;
zval_copy_ctor(return_value);
```